# How to use 'shinytest' with 'golem'?

Tags: r, shiny, golem, shinytest

I'm new to '***golem***'. So far I did my Shiny apps as packages, with the app in the folder **inst/app**, and then to use '***shinytest***' I made a folder **inst/app/shinytest**. How to do with '***golem***'? There's no app folder: **inst/app** only contains **www**, and the UI and the server are some functions in the package.

So I need to know where to put the '***shinytest***' script and how to deal with '***testthat***' and the `expect_pass` function? (I don't want to use `testServer`)

Answer (score 0):

I've found. It suffices to create a file **app.R** in the **app** folder with these contents:

```
mypackage::run_app()
```